# Cypress: Finding the content of a specific td element

Tags: cypress

I need to find the content of a specific td element based on the content of the next td element in the row.

The markup (simplified):

```
<table id="oversiktOverSoknaderTable">
 <tr data-e2e-selector="soknad-linje">
  <td data-e2e-selector="status">Trukket</td>
   <td data-e2e-selector="soknadProsjektNavn">Endret søknad</td>
   <td>Lån</td>
   <td data-e2e-selector="soknadId" id="2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-e2e-selector="soknad-linje">
  <td> ...
```

There can be multiple rows, all with the same selector (data-e2e-selector="soknad-linje">. The issue at hand is to verify that the correct status is showing for the correct name. (Sorry for not translating the selector names, but I think they're quite self-explanatory.)

What I want to do, is to use .should('contain'.'value') to verify that the text in the data-e2e-selector="status" quals "Trukket" for the line where the data-e2e-selector="soknadProsjektNavn" is "Endret søknad". (As it is in the above example.)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting **detached from DOM** error, try keeping the commands preceding `.should()` (which triggers retry) as short as possible.

```js
cy.contains('[data-e2e-selector="soknad-linje"]', 'Endret søknad') // row with project
  .should('contain', 'Trukket')                                    // confirm the status
```

or

```js
cy.get('[data-e2e-selector="soknad-linje"]')
  .should('contain', 'Endret søknad') 
  .should('contain', 'Trukket')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Endret søknad` is a unique value in your table.

Since you have `data-e2e-selector` in your elements you can use the follow

```js
cy.get('#oversiktOverSoknaderTable') // hopefully this is unique enough
  .should('be.visible') // assertion to avoid element detached from DOM

cy.contains('[data-e2e-selector="soknad-linje"]', 'Endret søknad') // gets row with unique string
  .should('be.visible')
  .find('[data-e2e-selector="status"]') // searches in row for element
  .should('have.text', 'Trukket') // has status text
```

Comment: I like this solution. However - it works perfectly when running the test locally. However, in Tekton (the build/test environment), it fails with "Timed out retrying after 10000ms: cy.should() failed because this element is detached from the DOM." It's strange, becuase I'm looking at the video of the test running and faling, and the element is perfectly visible when Cypress claims that it's detached from the dom.

Comment: Sounds like a table assertion is needed for this. I'll add that.

Comment: "detached from the DOM" - looks like the test code is running before the table is fully populated (i.e the table gets re-rendered when status info is fetched). If so, `.should('be.visible')` won't be enough. Try adding `.should('contain', 'Trukket')` to the table element. There's not really enough info in the question, but here's one wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you can do

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Endret søknad')
  .sibling('[data-e2e-selector="status"]')
  .should('contain', 'Trukket')
```

where `sibling()` takes a selector to specify which one.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `.prev()` command.

Like @jjhelguero I would also recommend being specific with `data-e2e-selector` in the selector.

```js
cy.contains('td[data-e2e-selector="soknadProsjektNavn"]', 'Endret søknad') 
  .prev('td[data-e2e-selector="status"]') 
  .should('have.text', 'Trukket')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Endret søknad')
  .parent('tr')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('[data-e2e-selector="status"]').should('have.text', 'Trukket')
  })
```